# Criteria lançando Java heap space devido ao tamanho da Clausula Restrictions.in()

Tags: java, criteria

Estou tentando executar uma consulta  utilizando Criteria mas ela está retornando uma Exceção de "Java heap".
Provavelmente deve ser pelo volume de dados que  estou passando nas cláusulas "in"

aqui em baixo um código que representa minha consulta:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Classe1.class, "C1");
c.createAlias("C1.itens", "Itens");
c.createAlias("Itens.nros", "Nros");
c.createAlias("Itens.estados", "Estados");
c.createAlias("C1.janelas", "Janelas");
c.createAlias("C1.criador", "Criador");
c.createAlias("C1.xamines", "Xamines");
c.createAlias("C1.torres", "Torres");
c.add(Restrictions.in("Nros.id", "lista com aprox 40 registros"));
c.add(Restrictions.in("Estados.id", "lista com aprox 5000 registros"));
c.add(Restrictions.in("Criador.id", "lista com aprox 1500 registros"));
c.add(Restrictions.in("Xamines.id", "lista com aprox 50 registros"));
c.add(Restrictions.in("Torres.id", "lista com aprox 50 registros"))
        .addOrder(Order.asc("C1.id"));
c.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
long tempoFinal = System.currentTimeMillis();
List<Classe1> listass=c.list();
```

Não entendo quase nada de Criteria, portanto gostaria de saber se existe uma "Melhor" forma de executar está consulta.

ps: quando diminuo o tamanho das listas passadas nas clausulas "IN " para um tamanho pequeno, não ocorre o erro de "Java Heap".

Geralmente  cada C1 possui uns 3 a 4 "Itens" cada Item apenas 1"Nro".

Comment: Quantos registros existem em `C1`?

Comment: Aproximadamente 25 mil

Comment: Quantos estados e quantos nros cada `C1` tem em média?

Comment: não passam de 5 em todos os relacionamentos